# ffmpeg problems using avcodec_close

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ffmpeg

How is avcodec_close supposed to be called in ffmpeg?

This is the simplest code which reproduces my problem:

```
bool CDataSequenceFormat::openVideoCodec( AVStream* videoStream )
{
    AVCodecContext* codecContext = videoStream->codec;

    AVCodec* codec = avcodec_find_encoder(codecContext->codec_id);

    if (codec == NULL || avcodec_open2(codecContext, codec, NULL) < 0 || avcodec_is_open(codecContext)==0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    avcodec_close(codecContext);

    return true;
}
```

`avcodec_open2` doesn't return an error and `avcodec_is_open` returns 1, so I am assuming the `codecContext` has been set up properly. Am I wrong to assume this?

When I call `avcodec_close` immediately after, I get an access violation exception (writing to badf00d - but I thought avcodec_open2 handled the filling in of all the codec fields) somewhere in avcodec-54.dll

People seem to be getting segmentation faults when trying to call `avcodec_close` on an un-opened codec, but I don't think that's the case here.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**: I should have mentioned that I inherited this code which was using a fairly old version of ffmpeg and this problem only appeared when I updated to the latest ffmpeg tarball

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrote the class using the `output_example.c` example and it seemed to magically fix the problem.

On further investigation, it seems the problem was the order of `av_set_parameters`, `av_write_header` and `avcodec_open2`. The previous version of ffmpeg didn't seem to care that `avcodec_open` was called after `av_set_parameters` but doesn't actually fill in all the codec fields in the latest release unless it's called first